# Bullying terms in Kipling's "Stalky and Co." (contains spoilers)

Tags: meaning

In Rudyard Kipling's *Stalky and Co.* is a rather long scene when Stalky, Beetle and McTurk bully a pair of boys who have themselves been bullying a 'fag' (dated BrE usage: a junior pupil at a public school who does minor chores for a senior pupil). There are a number of methods they employ and some of those I have been able to find, though not easily, (head knuckling, cock fighting) but most (brush drill, corkscrew, giving the key, rocking a boy to sleep) I can find nothing about.

Are these tortures made up for the purpose of the story or are each these idioms/phrases previously established?

Comment: Are you asking us 'where to find them'? If that is your question, I don't think it's [on-topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @hank Please do not edit "fag" to "homosexual boy". I thought this only happened with auto edits but people would actually figure out that's not what the word means.  I'm fine to leave that out. Is this not about english language? How then does one understand the meaning of the words? Obviously "giving someone the key" doesn't mean literally handing him the key, and idioms seem to be on-topic no? Or should I try ELL maybe?

Comment: @DRF Until now, I was unaware of that meaning for fag. My apologies. I only changed it because I thought you were actually referring to a homosexual boy. If you would like to know definitions for idioms, then your question needs to be reworded to state that. As is stands, you asking about where to find more information about torture methods.

Comment: @hank Ahh I see reading the question again I can see how it would come off as that. Will edit. I will also edit the word out and keep the modern term.

Comment: I don't see how asking what phrases mean is off topic, Perhaps, DRF, if you edited out the question to make it unambiguously a request for help with the meaning of the terms, it might help. @Hank I don't see the fact of the question being about torture makes it off topic as long as the question is related to the meaning of the perm rather than the propriety of the techniques.

Comment: @Spagirl I agree, but only with a rewording. In it's original state, I was unable to see how definitions were being asked for, only information about the torture techniques. I do agree that meanings and even the origin of the terms is very much on topic.

Comment: @DRF Unfortunately, in America, that word has only one main use >.<

Comment: @Spagirl If you see the [revision 1](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/395767/revisions), you'd also maybe close it as off-topic.

Comment: It's fine to use _fag_ and whatever potentially offensive term inside the question body, answers and comments on condition that it is used for discussing the linguistic aspects of it and not to intentionally offend others.

Comment: @nvz I have edited it out since it didnt really add anything to the question. Having been listening to the book for a couple of days it's contemoporary American meaning didn't really jump out much as fags and fagging are used quite ubiquituously in the big in a very mildly pejorative meaning.

Comment: @NVZ, Revision 1 was what I did see, regardless of the wording it still seemed that what DRF wanted was to find out the meaning, which was why i suggested he reword it. 'Fag' as a junior boy carrying out some skivvying functions for older boys was part of Boarding School life and while the practice may now be regarded as unpleasant and dated, it is not, in context, an offensive term.

Comment: @Spagirl Nobody is still saying it's offensive. I was merely not aware of that BrE definition and usage. It was my mistake.

Comment: @Spagirl Nobody is saying it's an offensive term in this context. I was merely making the observation that _some_ people might be unaware of other senses for _fag_ and may feel offended reading it.

Comment: Hopefully they will take the time to read the comments and come to the same realization that I have.

Comment: Hank and NZV Folks have clearly been treating it as an offensive or potentially offensive term, and Hank, you have become aware of the intended meaning. I couldn't see that the pertinent meaning was identified in the thread and was intending its inclusion that help those who didn't know.

Comment: Good luck on your searches -- someone might find them. I might think they are types of mild boy to boy hazing (although back then they might have been worse.. and even today what used to be considered hyjinx seems to have a larger psychological impact and be more verbotten).  In my playground days there were things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedgie  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noogie and ... It might be hard to find definitions of what the equivalent of a 'wedgie' or a 'noogie' was without our modern cataloging of all such things on the internet.

Comment: I can't say that asking about these terms is off-topic (though they should be asked about one at a time), but you'd probably do better asking about them at some Kipling society.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are there online Kipling societies? I suppose there must be. I will try and check one. Apparently there is lot's of controversy about Kipling these days. Do you really think I should be asking about each of them separate? Given that they are similar (and that I suspect they might be all made up) it seemed like a reasonable question in total.

Comment: I've found ' “Here, my brother, your feathers need to be preened,” he said, rubbing his knuckles over H'ratli's head briskly. Head knuckling was a common enough event ...' in seconds in a Google search. But the number of results and the literary references indicate that the term is far from idiomatic. ELU is about accepted usages; rare inventions do not fit well with the site's ethos. And if you've not been able to track down the other examples, they're rare.

Comment: I think that the meaning of these phrases may have only been known to Kipling, and perhaps his school contemporaries.  They may have been invented simply to fire the reader's imagination as to what they might mean.

Comment: Oh come on @NVZ all English boarding school boys are self-confessed fags, at least while they're in boarding school.

Answer (score 1):

> Are these made up for the purpose of the story or are each these idioms/phrases previously established?

**They were likely established before Kipling's use.**

Actually, Kipling regularly took offence at the implication that he drew from an imaginary lexicon, rather than his world experiences.

Vast amounts of these words were documented, as described in [this book on slang](https://books.google.com/books?id=XaDHBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT323&ots=FuVCOdL0es&dq=Kipling%20slang&pg=PT321#v=onepage&q&f=false) which gives many examples, but unfortunately much has not made it from manuscript to internet.

Comment: Kipling also hated his boarding school experience, where he was regularly abused by older classmates and adults alike.

Answer (score 1):

"head knuckling" was in use when I was at school (1970's) in Dublin, Ireland. It meant literally that: A boy, holding another boy in "head lock", dragging his clenchfisted knuckles (perhaps "knuckles of his clenched fist"?) backward and forward on another boy's scalp. Most painful in my memory!

Comment: In current US usage, this would be a "noogie".

Comment: @Kirt: I'll attempt to avoid a noogie, then!